# Trying to enter the BIOS setup with the F10 key hangs my HP Spectre x360 13

Tags: laptop, bios, spectre

This question is not about how to get into the BIOS but a slightly different problem: to make the story short (TL;DR): when I hit F10, the machine does not go to BIOS setup but is stuck.

Long version: on my HP Spectre x360 laptop (mid-2018), with a F41 bios (updated from F40, updated from F34), I can get the to initial menu, after a surprisingly long time (than it was before). From this menu, hitting F10 should take me to the BIOS setup and under the menu there is a picture of a small keyboard. When I hit the F10 key, this picture disappears and then the machine is stuck forever. The fan goes to high-speed, the machine gets much hotter but nothing more happen. The BIOS setup screen should appear instantly, which is not the case anymore (I waited up until 10 minutes, just in case).

In the end, I cannot get into the BIOS setup anymore. The problem is the same with BIOS F40 and F41.

I tried:

- to update the BIOS. It didn't work with F40. It doesn't work with F41 either
- to reset the CMOS. It didn't' work
- to access using Esc+F10 just a power on time (tapping many times Esc or F10). In fact, this didn't do anything at all. My computer was stuck on a black screen.
- to remove the SSD disk to see if it was blocking anything

None of this had any effect and I cannot pass the BIOS menu selection. Again, when trying to go into BIOS setup, it hangs.

I'm not sure it has any impact but my machine has a dual-boot (Ubuntu 20.10) and therefore a GRUB bootloader. Getting to the main BIOS menu (not the BIOS setup) seems only possible from the GRUB menu. The ESC or F10 tapping at boot time doesn't work anymore. Strange indeed...

Any idea?

Comment: recover the bios>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04126730

Comment: I know this page and none of their solutions work. I tried resetting the CMOS, try to re-install the BIOS, tried Win+V, Win+B, but I just can't access to the BIOS setup as explained above, and did a test of the SSD just in case it was the problem with it. The Diagnostic tool (in the BIOS, not in Windows) detected nothing wrong.

Apart from that, this computer works very well. I use it everyday (with Ubuntu by the way).

Comment: Unless you post what you have tried we are in the dark, we cannot read minds

Comment: @Moab: I've edited the question with more details. Thanks